# find_one_and_update + inc counter ONLY when inserting

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I was hoping to write a simple pymongo query to 'find' (if exists) or 'insert (if not exists) and return the object.

find_one_and_update + upsert seems to do what I want.

I have a separate counter in db.counters, which keeps track of a unique auto-increment ID for my (family).

The below code works as expected, if the 'family' does not yet exist, then it inserts it and returns the 'family_id' (int), if it does exist, then it returns the 'family_id'.

```
family = db.family.find_one_and_update(
            { "external_cohort_id": external_cohort_id, "external_family_id": external_family_id },
            { "$setOnInsert": { "external_cohort_id": external_cohort_id, 
                            "external_family_id": external_family_id, 
                            "family_id": self.get_next_seq("ir-family") }},
            projection={'family_id': True, '_id': False},
            upsert=True,
            new=True,
            return_document=pymongo.ReturnDocument.AFTER
        )
```

The obvious issue is that the self.get_next_seq("ir-family") is always evaluated, which auto-increments my counter, every time.  I only want to INC the next 'family_id' in the counter ONLY when inserting, not for every request.

Is there a simpler way to do this?  I don't believe splitting this into multiple queries will be able to handle concurrent updates.

Comment: Not here you cannot. The obvious problem is that the code of course evaluates "before" the instruction is sent to the server. If this is your case then "upsert" is not for you. Instead you should attempt to "update" and when that action results in no data modified ( should be exposed as `nModified` or similar in the response ) then your action would be an "insert". It's not an atomic operation and requires a response from the server, but if you have such an external constraint in your code, then you have no other option. Maybe you should rethink this design point.

Comment: Thanks that helps - will think abut a redesign here.  Or if the design stays the same, it looks like a two-phase-commit pattern may help? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/